# Using lapply instead of for loop in r

Tags: r

I am having trouble writing a function to replace a for() loop in R.

My data looks like this:

```
dat1<-rep(sprintf("%02d", 0:52),10)
dat1<-as.data.frame(dat1[40:length(dat1)])
colnames(dat1)<-c("wk")
wk.seas<-c(rep("win",9),rep("spr",13),rep("sum",13),rep("aut",13),rep("win",6))
wks<-sprintf("%02d", 0:53)
```

This loop produces what I want:

```
for(j in seq_along(dat1[,1])){
    dat1$season[dat1[,1]==wks[j]]<-wk.seas[j]
}#works
```

I am looking to create a vector in the df with a value for season that corresponds to the week of the year.

Here is my attempt to replicate this loop with a function/lapply combo:

```
lapply(seq_along(dat1$wk), function(d){
    dat1$season[dat1$wk==wks[d]]<-wk.seas[d]
}) #not working
```

Thank you
(edited to add missing code)

Comment: but your loop doesn't produce what you want it returns, Error: object 'wk.seas' not found.

Comment: @user sorry, I didn't copy everything I needed to- it should work now

Comment: do you have a code as to what each of the seasons constitute?  Eg, what numbers do "win" cover etc etc, if so you could take that approach.

Comment: @CDVAK why do you want to use lapply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a bunch of ways to solve the problem, but two quick solutions come to mind:

1. `Ifelse`:

`dat1$seas <- ifelse(dat1$wk>=15 & dat1$wk<41, "summer", NA)`

2. Base commands:

`dat1[dat1$wk>=15 & dat1$wk<45,2] <- "summer"`

You'd want one for each season that you want to designate.

Also, upon creation dat1$wk is being formatted as a factor; I had to pass `dat1$wk <- as.numeric(dat1$wk)` in order to be able to do either of the above.

EDIT: +1 for merge/join, if you have the season table elsewhere.

Comment: I used five lines of the  "2. Base commands" code to add the seasons instead of trying to write a function to do it in one step. Thanks,

Comment: Just to circle back on this-merge as below is the correct approach if you have the list of seasons and their criteria listed out. I posted this reply to a later-edited version of your question.

Answer (score 4):

`lapply` is the wrong approach.  The reason that the `lapply` code above doesn't work is because you're modifying an object within a function, which modifies a local copy in the function's environment.  Any of the `apply` functions will capture the return value and aggregate that; you should not rely on function side-effects.

You're really performing a merge here.  Use `merge`:

```
wk <- data.frame(wk=wks, season=wk.seas)
merge(wk, dat1)
```